# How to prevent all hooks running before exit from being executed?

Tags: emacs, pymacs

I'm talking specifically about Pymacs, but this would be useful to know if anything like that happens in other circumstances.

The problem: when something goes wrong in Pymacs, it will no matter what try to restart itself, and especially so when it fails to start at all. But somehow it is adding a hook to run before any file (not necessary in Python mode) should be saved or closed. So, what happens - it becomes impossible to shut down Emacs in a "nice" way - I can only terminate the process from shell, because Pymacs would enter an infinite loop: when saving a file - it would try to restart itself, fail and prevent the file from being saved - since it failed, it'll prompt to restart - no matter if I answer yes or no to restarting it, it will fail and ask again to restart itself.

`M-x unload-feature` doesn't help because it can't unload it (because .emacs loads it). I'm not sure at all by the way if the `unload-feature` can ever do anything meaningful :| I was trying to evaluate `(setq kill-buffer-hook nil)` but this didn't seem to help either. Perhaps there are some other hooks? Is there a way to force `unload-feature` to actually do something? In this situation I'd prefer save file and crash, then infinite loop and no crash, but file not saved situation.

Comment: there is also a `remove-hook`., did you try that? or you can bluntly put hook to nil using setq.

Comment: Pymacs has some function/variable (I don't remember now) to disable auto reconnect. did yo check it?

Comment: found it, https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs/blob/master/pymacs.el.in#L133 put that to `nil`

Comment: actually your title of this question is still very valid and good, may be some one else will chip in and answer